# problems with an edit form/view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I work with Django 1.9. I created a view to add a new object and it works, but when to create a view to edit the objects, I have two different problems:

- when I want to edit an album I click the link to the page where I want to see the entire list of albums for editing, but I get the error `Exception Type: NameError` and `Exception Value: name 'album' is not defined` that relates -> views.py in mod_artist  `form = AlbumForm(instance=album)`
- instead, when I want to edit an artist, I do the same thing as before to see the whole list of artists to be able to edit, but I get the error `Exception Type:
  UnboundLocalError` and `Exception Value: local variable 'artist' referenced before assignment` that relates -> views.py in mod_artist `form = ArtistForm(instance=artist)`

my `views.py` file is

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .forms import *
from .models import *

def mod_album(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AlbumForm(request.POST, instance=album)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
else:
    form = AlbumForm(instance=album)
return render(request,'polls/mod_album.html',{'form':form})

def mod_artist(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ArtistForm(request.POST, instance=artist)
    if form.is_valid():
        artist = form.save(commit=False)
        artist.author = request.user
        artist.save()
        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
else:
    form = ArtistForm(instance=artist)
return render(request,'polls/mod_artist.html',{'form':form})
```

my `index.html` file is

```
...
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="header">
            <div>
                <h1>personal library</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="wrap-nav">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="new_album" class="navbar-link">+ add album</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="mod_album" class="navbar-link">- edit album</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="new_artist" class="navbar-link">+ add artist</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="mod_artist" class="navbar-link">- edit artist</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="result" class="navbar-link">view the list of albums</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                {% for album in albums %}
                <ul>
                    <li>Album name: {{album.name}}</li>
                    <li>Artist: {{album.artist}}</li>
                    <li>Genre: {{album.genre}}</li>
                    <li>Songs: , </li>
                    <li>Vote: {{album.vote}}</li>
                </ul>
                <hr />
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                {% for artist in artists %}
                <ul>
                    <li>Artist name: {{artist.name}}</li>
                </ul>
                <hr />
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

my `urls.py` file is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
     ...
     url(r'^new_album/$', views.new_album, name='new_album'),
     url(r'^mod_album/$', views.mod_album, name='mod_album'),
     url(r'^new_artist/$', views.new_artist, name='new_artist'),
     url(r'^mod_artist/$', views.mod_artist, name='mod_artist'),
]
```

and my `forms.py` file is

```
from django import forms
from .models  import *

class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['name','artist','year','genre','vote']

class ArtistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ['name']
```

thanks in advance of our time.

Comment: You are using the url `/mod_album/` - that contains no information about which album you wish to edit. I think you'd find it useful to work through the tutorial. In particular, [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/) creates a view `detail` which will handle views like `/polls/3/` (which shows the details for the object with id=3).

Comment: Ah okay! I thought it was not necessary. thanks for the answer, and now I try.

Comment: When you are using `form = ArtistForm(instance=artist)` in the else clause, and the `artist` variable is being generated in the if clause above, there was bound to be an Exception. Please declare `artist` in the else clause also, and then use `form = ArtistForm(instance=artist)`. Hope, it helps.